# Reset Admin Password for Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

Managed to lock my admin account for my local acumatica and found an bit of sql that helped prompt me with entering a new password however it doesn't stick.

```
UPDATE Users SET Password = ‘123’, LockedOutDate =null WHERE CompanyID = 2 AND Username = ‘admin’
```

I'm using Acumatica Framework 2020 R1 and sql express 2017. Can't get pass the screen to enter new password screen and not failing with any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a copy/paste, your single quote marks were incorrect for me.  I corrected to normal apostrophes, and your statement worked for me for my admin user in "CompanyID = 2".

```
UPDATE Users SET Password = '123', LockedOutDate =null WHERE CompanyID = 2 AND Username = 'admin'
```

Is this multi-tenant?  If so, are you logging into the tenant that is CompanyID = 2?  It is possible that your Company ID is not 2, as I have seen where we created a new tenant and removed an old tenant in our DEV instance.  If you only have 1 tenant, you could try CompanyID <> 1.  Just remember to set your password in each tenant to match if there is more than 1.  The login process compares your user id and password to all tenants avaialble.  If you select your tenant on initial login, then you must pick the tenant that contains your new password.

Answer (score 1):

I have found it best to also reset the LockedOutDate, LastLockedOutDate, and FailedPasswordAttemptCountfields in get past the lock out.

`UPDATE Users SET Password = '123', LockedOutDate =null, LastLockedOutDate =null, FailedPasswordAttemptCount=0,  WHERE CompanyID = 2 AND Username = 'admin'`

Answer (score 1):

When system locked my account, I used this code.

USE [DATABASENAME]
GO
UPDATE Users SET Password = 'YourPassword', LockedOutDate =null WHERE Username = 'username'

Here are described the details and the reasons of the process —
[Reset Acumatica User Password](https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2015/12/reset-user-password.html)